# 'Split horizon DNS service' with BIND on windows 7,how to configure?

Tags: dns, opendns, bind

I want to set up 'forwarding proxy DNS server' on my windows 7,so that i can perform conditional forwarding on my 'ISP's login website' because the way to load the login page of my ISP's website is to use their DNS address.

I did search a lot,but i ended up with articles that show how to configure BIND on linux system.

This is my previous question,please take a look for further information. [Open Dns on my router giving problems](https://superuser.com/questions/385486/open-dns-on-my-router-giving-problems/)