# Use different DNS servers for different domains?

Tags: dns, opendns

I have windows 7,i want to configure different dns servers for different websites.
My isp's login page only works with his dns server,if i use open dns..i cant load up my isp login page.
So i want to use my isp's dns server to load isp;s login page and for other sites i want to use OpenDns.

Is there a software to do this?
i would prefer a batch file or something like that.
Thanks.

Comment: [You asked this last week](http://superuser.com/questions/385486/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep things simple.

**If** the only problem you have is the access to the ISP login page, just add the url and ip adress of this page in the HOSTS file to avoid a DNS request for this web page...

The syntax is *{URL} {at least one space} {IPv4 Address}*

Somethings like: MyISPLoginPage.com 12.123.123

BTW: if you want to discover the bests DNS servers for you, use this software: *NameBench*

http://code.google.com/p/namebench/

Hope this help. Let us know.

P.S. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS

Comment: Can i use OpenDns dns server address in the 'Preferred Dns server' field, and my isp's dns server in the 'Secondary Dns server' field.So that when i load up my Isp's login page,the Preferred Dns server fails and the secondary dns server is used.

Comment: Yes, that's a perfect example of why there are two entries for dns.

Comment: The syntax is `{hostname} {ipv4 address}`  the hosts file does not know anything about URLS which include things like protocol specifiers  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/url

Comment: The primary DNS won't fail, it will return a valid response stating that the name doesn't exist (according to its records). The client won't (and shouldn't) fail over to the secondary DNS server in that case - that would only happen when it receives *no response at all*.

Answer (score 1):

If its only your ISP's domain that's a problem, you can edit your host file to hardcode that value and use opendns for everything else.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows it isn't possible to use a different DNS for different websites. If only your ISP's page doesn't work in OpenDNS, you could configure your hosts file with the IP of the website and use OpenDNS for DNS resolving.

Another option would be to use a secondary DNS. In Windows you can configure several DNS servers, number 1 would be your ISP's DNS, number 2 openDNS or the other way around.

This link describes how to configure your DNS:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15037-dns-addressing-how-change-windows-7-a.html

Comment: -1 for suggesting [an approach that doesn't work](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-client-all-proxies-must-provide-same-service.html).